# What is a Kolmogorov inequality, and why?

Tags: probability, statistics, concentration-of-measure, empirical-processes

I encountered a problem while reading a classic paper.
The random variable $V \sim exp(1)$, $(v_{(1)},v_{(2)},...,v_{(n)})$ are ordered. The paper said, for any $\epsilon$, based on the Kolmogorov inequality, there exist $v_{in}$ and $v^{in}$,$$sup_{1\leq i\leq n}[v^{in}-v_{in}]\leq K(\epsilon)$$ and $$
P\left\{v_{i n}(\epsilon)<v_{(i )}<v^{i n}(\epsilon), 1 \leq i \leq n\right\} \geq 1-\epsilon
$$

It is the proposition 4 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-38/issue-1/Asymptotic-Distribution-of-Linear-Combinations-of-Functions-of-Order-Statistics/10.1214/aoms/1177699058.full)(p56). It doesn’t seem to be difficult from the writing tone, but I cannot understand. And I think it is not the maximal inequality which is called as Kolmogorov inequality.

Thank you!

Comment: What does $v^{in}$ mean, for example when $n=5$ and $i=2$?

Comment: @Henry It says $v^{in}$ is an existing constant depending on n and i  meets the two conditions in the question,

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Comment: Your desired result is a corollary of the convergence of the empirical distribution function

Comment: @Bananach I know the Glivenko-Cantelli thm and DKW ineq. I can only get $|F(v^{in})-F(v_{in})|$ go to 0 uniformly, but $F^{-1}$ is not lipschitz.

Comment: Please note Proposition 3 and use Kolmogorov Ineq. for $V_{jn}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^j\dfrac{Z_i}{n-i+1}$.

Comment: @JGWang Thank you very much!